# Parity of the number of inversions in a sliding puzzle

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, algorithm, sorting

Given the definition of inversion as below

***Inversions:***
Given a board, an inversion is any pair of tiles i and j where i < j but i appears after j when considering the board in row-major order (row 0, followed by row 1, and so forth).

[image]

I have an array like

`arr = [1, 20, 6, 4, 22 , 5 , 12 , 3];`

and a function to count the number of inversions:

```
function getInvCount(arr){
let inv_count = 0;
for(let i=0; i<arr.length-1; i++){
    for(let j=i+1; j<arr.length; j++){
        if(arr[i] > arr[j]) inv_count++;
    }
}
return inv_count;
```

}

what I want to do is if the number of inversions is odd, make changes to the array so that it gives me an even number of inversions.

How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact (kudos to @MattTimmermans for noticing that), swapping any pair of elements - not just consecutive - should work here.

Let's take your function...

```
function getInvCount(arr){
  let inv_count = 0;
  for(let i=0; i<arr.length-1; i++){
    for(let j=i+1; j<arr.length; j++){
        if(arr[i] > arr[j]) inv_count++;
    }
  }
}

arr[0] => compared with arr[1], ..., arr[k], arr[k + 1], ..., arr[k + x], ..., arr[-1]
arr[1] => compared with arr[2], ..., arr[k], arr[k + 1], ..., arr[k + x], ..., arr[-1]
...
arr[k]     => compared with arr[k + 1], arr[k + 2], ..., arr[k + x], ..., arr[-1]
arr[k + 1] => compared with arr[k + 2], arr[k + 3], ..., arr[k + x], ..., arr[-1]
... 
arr[k + x] => compared with arr[k + x + 1], arr[k + x + 2], ..., arr[-2], arr[-1]
...
```

... and analyze it, assuming we've swapped the elements with `k` and `k+x` indexes. How did that change the result?

```
arr[0] => compared with arr[1], ..., arr[k + x], arr[k + 1], ..., arr[k], ..., arr[-1]
arr[1] => compared with arr[2], ..., arr[k + x], arr[k + 1], ..., arr[k], ..., arr[-1]
...
arr[k + x] => compared with arr[k + 1], arr[k + 2], ..., arr[k], ..., arr[-1]
arr[k + 1] => compared with arr[k + 2], arr[k + 3], ..., arr[k], ..., arr[-1]
...
arr[k] => compared with arr[k + x + 1], arr[k + x + 2], ..., arr[-2], arr[-1]
...
```

Well, not by much actually. Any element preceding `arr[k]` is still compared with **both** `arr[k]` and `arr[k + x]` - just in a different order (comparison with `arr[k + x]` goes first now). And any element following those is still not compared with these elements at all. So all the `if(arr[i] > arr[j])` checks from the previous 'state' are still there, and apparently their result is the same.

The only changed comparisons are in `[k, k+x]` range. For the first row, here's how the checks are changed:

```
a[k] > a[k + 1] is replaced by a[k + x] > a[k + 1]
a[k] > a[k + 2] is replaced by a[k + x] > a[k + 2]
...
a[k] > a[k + x] is replaced by a[k + x] > a[k]
```

It seems to hard to predict how does this affect the count, as there's no guarantee how big those numbers are. But let's see how the checks for the following line are affected:

```
a[k + 1] > a[k + 2] => the same
a[k + 1] > a[k + 3] => the same
...
a[k + 1] > a[k + x] => a[k + 1] > a[k]
...
```

Now, we can see there is just a pair of replaced checks involving a[k + 1] element:

```
a[k] > a[k + 1] => a[k + x] > a[k + 1]
a[k + 1] > a[k + x] => a[k + 1] > a[k]
```

And this is the key: no matter what's `a[k + 1]` value is, it's exactly two checks *reversed* here. The same, in fact, is true for any number between k and k + x. Only for `a[k + x]` element, there's exactly one swap:

```
a[k] > a[k + x] => a[k + x] > a[k]
```

That's why, regardless of which numbers you swap, the difference will be an odd number. The exact number of "inversion diff" will be equivalent to (x - 1) * 2 + 1, so it's strictly 1 for consecutive numbers, 3 for the ones separated by a single element, etc.

Comment: It doesn't matter what pair you swap.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Ah, but you're right of course. ) Updated the answer.